# How to watch kubernetes event details using it's go client?

Tags: go, client, kubernetes

In kubernetes dashboard, you can view events for a namespace: eg"
pulling image "hello-world",Successfully pulled image "hello-world",etc.

Is there a way to get all these events using the it's go client?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This other client looks pretty good https://godoc.org/bitbucket.org/amdatulabs/amdatu-kubernetes-go/client#Client.WatchPodsWithLabel

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`NewInformer()`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/450baa5d60f8d6a251c7682cb6f86e939b750b2d/tools/cache/controller.go#L276) function to create a notifications for specific type events.

Here is a minimum example ([source](https://solinea.com/blog/tapping-kubernetes-events)):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api"
    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache"
    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/restclient"
    client "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/unversioned"
    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/fields"
    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait"
)

func podCreated(obj interface{}) {
    pod := obj.(*api.Pod)
    fmt.Println("Pod created: " + pod.ObjectMeta.Name)
}
func podDeleted(obj interface{}) {
    pod := obj.(*api.Pod)
    fmt.Println("Pod deleted: " + pod.ObjectMeta.Name)
}
func watchPods(client *client.Client, store cache.Store) cache.Store {
    //Define what we want to look for (Pods)
    watchlist := cache.NewListWatchFromClient(client, "pods", api.NamespaceAll, fields.Everything())
    resyncPeriod := 30 * time.Minute
    //Setup an informer to call functions when the watchlist changes
    eStore, eController := framework.NewInformer(
        watchlist,
        &api.Pod{},
        resyncPeriod,
        framework.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
            AddFunc:    podCreated,
            DeleteFunc: podDeleted,
        },
    )
    //Run the controller as a goroutine
    go eController.Run(wait.NeverStop)
    return eStore
}
func main() {
    //Configure cluster info
    config := &amp
    restclient.Config{
        Host:     "https://xxx.yyy.zzz:443",
        Username: "kube",
        Password: "supersecretpw",
        Insecure: true,
    }
    //Create a new client to interact with cluster and freak if it doesn't work
    kubeClient, err := client.New(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Client not created sucessfully:", err)
    }
    //Create a cache to store Pods
    var podsStore cache.Store
    //Watch for Pods
    podsStore = watchPods(kubeClient, podsStore)
    //Keep alive
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. However I want to get all types of events for the kube clusters. Is there any sample for using kube event api?

Comment: This does not build as `k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg` appears to have been significantly refactored. Do you have a work around with updated dependencies that compiles?

Comment: @nmurthy, no, I haven't done anything similar recently.